# Flask APScheduler fetching old route

Tags: python, html, flask, web-development-server, apscheduler

I am new to Flask. I am using the APScheduler to fetch a list every minute.

```
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler

scheduler = APScheduler()

# define the route
@app.route('/recent_news', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def recent_news():
    return render_template("recent-news.html", result=news_data)

# configure the scheduler to run the update_news_data function every 1 minute
scheduler.add_job(func=update_news_data, trigger='interval', minutes=1, id='test')
scheduler.start()
```

However I keep getting 404 on a route \update-data as shown below. I had a route by that name but I deleted it. I don't have any route or anything by that name anymore in the python code or in HTML.

I tried reloading the webpage, restarting the flask server and running scheduler.shutdown() but I am still getting the 404.

[image]

I would be grateful for any help on this.